# How can I use SQL BETWEEN to compare two dates in a string to execute to sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion, sp-executesql

I have a line in my SQL Stored Procedure that looks like this (works as intended):

```
HAVING  oh.startdate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

However, further down I have the line:

```
AND (oh.user IN (@userIDs))
```

Where @userIDs is a comma delimited string of ID's and oh.user is an INTEGER, so I must actually put the entire SQL query into a dynamic string (@sql) with all the parameters concatenated into it and then use

```
sp_executesql @sql
```

Everything is working fine except the BETWEEN dates, I've tried a few ways and keep getting errors or no results returned when there should be:

```
    HAVING  oh.startdate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '+LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @startDate, 120), 10)+', 120) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '+LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @endDate, 120), 10)+', 120)
```

returns nothing.

```
    HAVING  oh.startdate '+LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @startDate, 120), 10)+' AND '+LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @endDate, 120), 10)+'
```

also returns nothing.

```
    HAVING  oh.startdate BETWEEN ' + @startDate +' AND '+ @endDate +'
```

returns error converting DATETIME to string.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: can you post your entire query, some sample data and your expected results?

Comment: what type are you using for oh.startdate, @startDate and @endDate?

Comment: and tell us what date format is used. (ex: '21-jan-20012' or '21/01/2012')

Comment: @FrancisP thanks for the input, the answer below worked perfectly.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for your input, the answer below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sp_executesql` and pass the parameters you want:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT blabla FROM Table WHERE Something HAVING oh.startdate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@startDate DATE, @EndDate DATE',@startDate, @EndDate
```

Comment: Wow. I did not know you can do that. Thanks so much! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HAVING  oh.startdate BETWEEN to_date(@startDate,'dd-MM-yyyy') AND to_date(@endDate,'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

and change the 'dd-MM-yyyy' to fit the date format you are using.